# How can I make a linearLayout (with other views and content within) to be clickable in android studio xml and using Kotlin in the backend?

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I have created a linearLayout in a constraintLayout which is also in a scrollView and now I want to make just the liniearLayout to be launching a new activity when clicked upon by the user. This is the code;

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/viewDivider"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutHeader">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutServices"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_rectangle_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/layoutOperatorLogin"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/experience"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Services"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/googlesans_bold"/>

            </LinearLayout>
       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to start a new activity whenever someone clicks on LinearLayout,i.e., layoutServices.

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val linearLayout = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.layoutService)
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener {
            //replace MainActivity with Activity you want to launch
            val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            this.activity?.finish()
        }
}
```